# Movement and Jump doesn't work simultaneously

Tags: unity-game-engine

What to change here to my character moves forward and can also jump?

```
public class PlayerJump : MonoBehaviour {

    public float jumpForce = 10f;

    private Rigidbody2D myRB;

    public float speed = 2f;

    void Start () {
        myRB = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    public void FixedUpdate () {
        myRB.velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
    }

    public void Jump () {
        myRB.velocity = new Vector2 (myRB.velocity.x, jumpForce);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please re-format your code, and preferably provide a complete example to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vector2.right` is `Vector2(1, 0)`, so all your vertical velocity sets to 0 in fixed update. For moving, you need something similar what you have for jump (keep your vertical velocity).

`myRB.velocity = new Vector2(speed, myRB.velocity.y);`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpHeight, ForceMode2D.Impulse);` what's happening is that you are resetting your vertical velocity when you are moving. So you also need to take into account your current velocity on your y axis, using `myRB.velocity = new Vector2(speed, myRB.velocity.y);`